# How to use FrameLayout inside RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-progressbar, android-framelayout

I want to use a framelayout inside a recycler view. the framelayout is defined in a custom class which contains 2 things: a loading spinner and a button.

when the user click button, i want the button to hide and loading spinner to show.

custom class layout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/foreground"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/SG_White"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true">

        <ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_loader"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:visibility="@{model.showSpinnerTrue}" />

        //BUTTON CODE
</FrameLayout>
```

but I am getting this bad error:

```
Process: com.application.debug, PID: 1442
    java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unsupported view type supplied: 2131558525
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onMeasure(RecyclerView.java:3540)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.measureChildWithMargins(ScrollView.java:2365)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.widget.ScrollView.onMeasure(ScrollView.java:691)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:146)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:490)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:7845)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:1016)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:26414)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3609)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:2352)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2644)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2204)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:9069)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:999)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:797)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:732)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:984)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8125)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:496)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1100)
```

i think this error means I cannot use framelayout in recyclerview?

if not, how to show a loading spinner on top of a specific index in recyclerview?

Comment: You can add Header in RecyclerView that has ProgressBar layout

Comment: Do you want to show progress bar on each item which is not loaded ?

Comment: so each recycler view will show a button by default. when i click the button say on index 4 of recycloerview, the index 4 button will disapper and in the pace of index 4, the loading indicator needs to show (hiding the button behind it)

Answer (score 0):

I think the FrameLayout is not meant to be the items of a recycler view. It will be better for you to use a linear layout instead because it is easier, and if you don't want that, you can use a Card View, which I think is really suitable in a recycler view and more attractive for the user.

Comment: but how it will allow me to swap between a loading progress spinner and button??